# listen to a collection add/change as a model attribute of a view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I have a Measure View, and it has an associated Measure Model, which has two collections, RepresentationsCollection and BeatsCollection.  The Measure View has nested child Representation views, each with their own representation model, and all representation models share the same attribute of a reference to the Measure View's BeatsCollection.

I know that if you are listening to a `change` event, the collection won't respond when something is added. You are supposed to use bind.  The docs aren't the best.  So if the child Representation View looks like this:

[image: here is a visual]

```
representation.View = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    // this.beatsCollection is a reference to the Parent Measure View attribute beatsCollection which is a collection
    this.model.listenTo(this, 'change:beatsCollection', this.render);
    this.model.on('change:beatsCollection', this.render, this);
    this.bind.listenTo(this, 'change:beatsCollection', this.render);
  },
```

and here is the model:

```
representation.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    console.log(options); 
    this.idAttribute = options.idAttribute;
    this.type = options.type;
    this.beatsCollection = options.beatsCollection;
 }
```

How do I listen for the attribute on this views associated model, which has an attribute, that is linked to a collection on another model?

Here is a [Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/z4mWqo1v0nDe13TiB9r3?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/z4mWqo1v0nDe13TiB9r3?p=preview)
First click 'add a representation'.
Second, click 'add a beat' and notice that the number of beats don't update.
Third, if you click 'add a representation' again, it will add another one with the correct number of beats.
In the Representation.js View, how do we get the Representation Views to re-render, when ANY of the sibling views click 'add a beat'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

updated Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/JtyxnhaGlPVijhbRPt5v?p=preview

trick was here in representation.View replacing

```
initialize: function(options) {
  if(options.model){this.model=options.model;}
  this.model.listenTo(this, 'change:beatsCollection', this.render);
  this.model.on('change:beatsCollection', this.render, this);
  this.model.on('change:beatsCollection', this.render, this);
  //this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
},
```

with

```
initialize: function(options) {
  if(options.model){this.model=options.model;}
  this.listenTo(this.model.beatsCollection,  'add remove reset', this.render);
},
```

Comment: This only listens to add.   Do i chain `remove` and `change` or should I use a `bind` or `bindAll`.  If so, how?

Comment: also note that beatsCollection is not a attribute of model, so change:beatsCollection never get triggered. Even if you make it an attribute, since they are passed by reference change:beatsCollection will never get triggered.

Comment: So even though it is stored as an attribute, I should still treat it like a Collection?

Comment: I would suggest continue using model.beatsCollection and keep listening to it like a collection. this makes code more readable, and take out the confusion of change event being triggered.

Comment: Note that setting `this.model` in the initialize function is unnecessary as Backbone does it for you.