# A proper example of backbone views: Change attributes, CRUD, without Zombie Views

Tags: backbone.js

Trying to make a reasonable teaching model of Backbone that shows proper ways to take advantage of backbone's features, with a grandparent, parent, and child views, models and collections...

I am trying to change a boolean attribute on a model, that can be instantiated across multiple parent views.  How do I adjust the listers to accomplish this?
The current problem is that when you click on any non-last child view, it moves that child to the end AND re-instantiates it.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/z4mWqo1v0nDe13TiB9r3?p=preview)
Click 'Add a representation'
Click 'Add a beat' (you can click this more than once)
Clicking any beat view other than the last one instantiates more views of the same beat

Child :

```
// our beat, which contains everything Backbone relating to the 'beat'
define("beat", ["jquery", "underscore", "backbone"], function($, _, Backbone) {
  var beat = {};

  //The model for our beat
  beat.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      selected: true
    },
    initialize: function(boolean){
      if(boolean) {
        this.selected = boolean;
      }
    }
  });

  //The collection of beats for our measure
  beat.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: beat.Model,
    initialize: function(){
      this.add([{selected: true}])
    }
  });

  //A view for our representation
  beat.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
      'click .beat' : 'toggleBeatModel'
    },
    initialize: function(options) {
      if(options.model){
        this.model=options.model;
        this.container = options.container;
        this.idAttr = options.idAttr;
      }
      this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
      this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
      // set the id on the empty div that currently exists
      this.$el.attr('id', this.idAttr);
      //This compiles the template
      this.template = _.template($('#beat-template').html());
      this.$el.html(this.template());
      //This appends it to the DOM
      $('#'+this.container).append(this.el);
      return this;
    },
    toggleBeatModel: function() {
      this.model.set('selected', !this.model.get('selected'));
      this.trigger('beat:toggle');
    }
  });

  return beat;
});
```

Parent :

```
// our representation, which contains everything Backbone relating to the 'representation'
define("representation", ["jquery", "underscore", "backbone", "beat"], function($, _, Backbone, Beat) {
  var representation = {};

  //The model for our representation
  representation.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
      this.idAttr = options.idAttr;
      this.type = options.type;
      this.beatsCollection = options.beatsCollection;
      //Not sure why we have to directly access the numOfBeats by .attributes, but w/e
    } 
  });  

  //The collection for our representations
  representation.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: representation.Model,
    initialize: function(){
    }
  });

  //A view for our representation
  representation.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
      'click .remove-representation' : 'removeRepresentation',
      'click .toggle-representation' : 'toggleRepType',
      'click .add-beat' : 'addBeat',
      'click .remove-beat' : 'removeBeat'
    },
    initialize: function(options) {
      if(options.model){this.model=options.model;}
      // Dont use change per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811524/listen-to-a-collection-add-change-as-a-model-attribute-of-a-view#24811700
      this.listenTo(this.model.beatsCollection,  'add remove reset', this.render);
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },
    render: function(){
      // this.$el is a shortcut provided by Backbone to get the jQuery selector HTML object of this.el
      // so this.$el === $(this.el)
      // set the id on the empty div that currently exists
      this.$el.attr('id', this.idAttr);
      //This compiles the template
      this.template = _.template($('#representation-template').html());
      this.$el.html(this.template());
      //This appends it to the DOM
      $('#measure-rep-container').append(this.el);
      _.each(this.model.beatsCollection.models, function(beat, index){
        var beatView = new Beat.View({container:'beat-container-'+this.model.idAttr, model:beat, idAttr:this.model.idAttr+'-'+index }); 
      }, this);
      return this;
    },
    removeRepresentation: function() {
      console.log("Removing " + this.idAttr);
      this.model.destroy();
      this.remove();
    },
    //remove: function() {
    //  this.$el.remove();
    //},
    toggleRepType: function() {
      console.log('Toggling ' + this.idAttr + ' type from ' + this.model.get('type'));
      this.model.set('type', (this.model.get('type') == 'line' ? 'circle' : 'line'));
      console.log('Toggled ' + this.idAttr + ' type to ' + this.model.get('type'));
      this.trigger('rep:toggle');
    },
    addBeat: function() {
      this.trigger('rep:addbeat');      
    },
    removeBeat: function() {
      this.trigger('rep:removebeat');      
    }
  });

  return representation;
});
```

This answer should be working properly for all views, being able to create, or delete views  without effecting non related views, and change attributes and have related views auto update.  Again, this is to use as a teaching example to show how to properly set up a backbone app without the zombie views...

Comment: where is 'this.trigger('beat:toggle');' this event being listened to?

Comment: Not sure we have a listener.  We preemptively put that there to try and listen for it in different place to make this problem go away.   Since we have the functionality working with just one 'beat' we didn't think we had to manage it elsewhere, but we noticed the problem when we had more than one beat.   No real need to have the trigger unless it helps resolve the stray beats.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've offered three bounties thus far, none have been awarded.   If you have an answer, let me know, and I'll award a high level to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

The reason you are seeing duplicate views created lies in the render() function for the Beat's view:

```
render: function(){
  // set the id on the empty div that currently exists
  this.$el.attr('id', this.idAttr);
  //This compiles the template
  this.template = _.template($('#beat-template').html());
  this.$el.html(this.template());
  //This appends it to the DOM
  $('#'+this.container).append(this.el);
  return this;
}
```

This function is called when:

1. when the model associated with the view changes
2. the beat view is first initialized

The first call is the one causing the problems. `initialize()` uses an event listener to watch for changes to the model to re-render it when necessary:

```
initialize: function(options) {
  ...
  this.model.on('change', this.render, this); // case #1 above
  this.render(); // case #2 above
  ...
},
```

Normally, this is fine, *except that `render()` includes code to push the view into the DOM*. That means that every time the model associated with the view changes state, the view not only re-renders, but is duplicated in the DOM.

This seems to cause a whole slew of problems in terms of event listeners being bound incorrectly. The reason, as far as I know, that this phenomenon isn't caused when there is just one beat present is because the representation itself also re-renders and removes the old zombie view. I don't entirely understand this behavior, but it definitely has something to do with the way the representation watches it's `beatCollection`.

## Solution

The fix is quite simple: change where the view appends itself to the DOM. This line in `render()`:

```
$('#'+this.container).append(this.el);
```

should be moved to initialize, like so:

```
initialize: function(options) {
  if(options.model){
    this.model=options.model;
    this.container = options.container;
    this.idAttr = options.idAttr;
  }
  this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
  this.render();
  $('#'+this.container).append(this.el); // add to the DOM after rendering/updating template
},
```

[Plnkr demo with solution applied](http://plnkr.co/edit/DBTuWJsUQNVQSdCWCDq4)